# Using MenuBar and Ribbon Simultaneously in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to achieve something like this
[image: MenuBar and ToolBar]

Is it possible in MFC? If yes, what is the ideal way?

Comment: That would be a really strange user interface.

Comment: Maybe you mean MenuBar + ToolBar? like Visual Studio interface.

Comment: Visual Studio toolbar doesn't group toolbar buttons like they have been done in the image above. Does MFC toolbar come with flexible enough functionality to mold it into something like the image shows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. I was demanded to do it and now have an application displaying a menu and a ribbon. In my case my main window class is derived from `CFrameWndEx` and it has a `CMFCMenuBar` member and a `CMFCRibbonBar`.

But I agree with @Michael Walz it is a strange interface.

The rest of the work, is your job to investigate...

BTW, the ribbon on your picture does not seem to be really a ribbon as it has no tabs on its top. Is really a ribbon you want, or are you speaking about a toolbar?

Comment: yes it is more of a toolbar, but the tools there have been grouped, like they are done in ribbonbar. But I dont need tabs.